# Pairs of blue socks

Tags: algebra-precalculus

John ordered $4$ pairs of black socks and some additional pairs of blue socks. The price of the black socks per pair was twice that of the blue. When the order was filled, it was found that the number of pairs of the two colors had been interchanged. This increased the bill by $50\%$. The ratio of the number of pairs of black socks to the number of pairs of blue socks in the original order was:

''Let the number of blue socks be represented as $b$. We are informed that the price of the black sock is twice the price of a blue sock; let us assume that the price of one pair of blue socks is $1$. That means the price of one pair of black socks is $2$.

Now from the third and fourth sentence, we see that $1.5(2(4)+1(b))=1(4)+2(b)$. Simplifying gives $b=16$. This means the ratio of the number of pairs of black socks and the number of pairs of blue socks is $\boxed{\textbf{(C)}\ 1:4}$''

What will the solution be without valuing prices? Just settle with variables

Comment: What do you mean by icons?

Comment: @79037662 lyrics

Comment: That doesn't help. What do you mean by lyrics?

Comment: @79037662 variables

Comment: Sure, just say one pair of blue socks costs $x$ and one pair of black socks costs $2x$, and use the exact same argument you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the price of blue socks be $p$.
For $b$ pairs of blue socks the total price is $bp$. The total price of the black socks will be $4\cdot2p$.
After the interchange, the total price for blue socks becomes $4\cdot p$ and the total price for the black socks becomes $b\cdot2p$. the new price is $1.5$ times the old price, so solving
$$1.5p(b+2\cdot4)=p(2b+4)$$
$p$ cancels out, as you said only the ratio of the quantities is relevant
$$1.5\cdot8-4=2b-1.5b$$
$$\fbox{b=16}$$